# Is it ever OK to catch Django ORM errors inside atomic blocks?

Tags: django, orm, transactions, atomic

Example code:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    # Create and save some models here

    try:
        model_instance.save()
    except IntegrityError:
        raise SomeCustomError()
```

Two questions:

1) Will this work as intended and roll back any previously saved models, given that nothing is done in the exception handler except for re-raising a custom error?

2) From a code style perspective, does it make sense to not use a nested transaction inside the `try` block in cases like this? (That is, only one line of code within the try block, no intention of persisting anything else within the transaction, no writes to the database inside the exception handler, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

***Will this work as intended and roll back any previously saved models, given that nothing is done in the exception handler except for re-raising a custom error?***

Yes. The rollback will be triggered by the exception (any exception), and as long as you don't touch the database after the database error you won't risk the `TransactionManagementError` mentioned in the documentation.

***From a code style perspective, does it make sense to not use a nested transaction inside the try block in cases like this?***

Style is a matter of opinion, but I don't see any point in using a nested transaction here. It makes the code more complicated (not to mention the unnecessary savepoints in the transaction) for no discernible benefit.

Comment: This makes sense for this case. What the line with the `get()` query were replaced with something that actually threw a database error?

Comment: @Alex3917: I've updated your example and my answer to be more on point. The real question was obscured by using a non-database error in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You should use atomic transaction like below code. Handle atomic transaction in catching block, avoid catching exceptions inside atomic.

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        SomeModel.objects.get(id=NON_EXISTENT_ID)
except SomeModel.DoesNotExist:
    raise SomeCustomError()
```